# RegEx to Match MM/YYYY

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have `^((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/(\d{4})$` to match `MM/YYYY`.

However, it does not match `9/2015`.

What do I have to change to make it match `9/2015` in addition to `09/2015`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a question mark after 0

```
^((0?[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/(\d{4})$
```

Answer (score 1):

It will not take `9/2015` because that does not match your format `MM/YYYY` If you want to match `M/YYYY OR MM/YYYY` you should use something like this

```
^(0[1-9]|1[0-2]|[1-9])/(\d{4})$
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the zero optional and get rid of the unnecessary capture groups:

```
^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/\d{4}$
   ^
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(0%3F%5B1-9%5D%7C1%5B0-2%5D)%2F%5Cd%7B4%7D%5Cr%3F%24&i=9%2F2015%0D%0A09%2F2105&o=m)

Note that the `?` quantifier meaning is *match the preceding subpattern 0 or more times*. Thus, the `0` will be either matched once or an empty string will do for the regex engine.

See [*Quantifiers in Regular Expressions*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details on quantifiers in regular expressions.